# error: expected ',' or ';' before 'for'

Tags: c++

I can't figure what's going on. I'm getting that error about my second for loop, the one that iterates through the map. This simple program, I thought, would find the most common element of an array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int mode(int* arr, int sz) { 
    std::map<int,int> M;
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
       if (M.count(arr[i]) == 0) { 
           M[arr[i]] = 1;
       } else { 
           M[arr[i]]++;
       }
    }
    int largest = arr[0]
    for (std::map<int,int>::iterator it = M.begin(); it != M.end(); it++) { 
       if (it->first > largest) {
           largest = it->first;
       }
    }
    return largest;
}

int main() {

  int myArray[] = {1, 2, 5, 0, 10, 4, -4, 10, 69, 10, 4, 4, 4}; 
  std::cout << "Mode = " << mode(myArray, sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(int));
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: I've reversed your edit. It raises a totally separate question, which should be a new post. You can't change a question after it's been answered in a way that invalidates those answers totally. It's unfair to the people who spent time answering your first question, and makes them look foolish because they've written something that no longer has meaning.

Answer (score 8):

You have a missing semi-colon ';'

```
int largest = arr[0]
                    ^
```

Answer (score 3):

You should add ; at the end of the previous line:

```
int largest = arr[0];
```